# Delete cookie when navigating away from specific page of a website

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am working on an e-shop php website. In my cart template page I defined a javascript cookie as I want to store a specific choice that a user does on this specific page. The code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("input[name=\"license-selector\"]").click(function(){ // when license-selector radio button is being clicked
    var thisElem = $(this);                             // value is being written to variable value
    var value = thisElem.val();
    //localStorage:
    sessionStorage.setItem("option", value);            // value stored in localstorage
    //Cookies:
    document.cookie="option="+value;                    // value stored in cookie
});
//localStorage:
var itemValue = sessionStorage.getItem("option");       // value is being loaded into variable itemValue


//Cookies:
var n = document.cookie;
if (n.indexOf("option=") !== -1) {
    var cookieValue = n.substring(n.indexOf("option=")+7, n.indexOf(";"))   // value is being loaded into variable cookieValue
        if (cookieValue == "su") {single_user()};
        if (cookieValue == "mu") {multi_user()};
    }
});
```

So, the cookie gets the value of a radio button that is being clicked. So far so good. The script is called from an external script file that is applied ONLY for this cart page.

Now, what I try to do is to delete this cookie whenever the user navigates away from this cart page (not from the website, but whenever the user decides to visit for example the products, the homepage etc of the same website I am working on). I want to delete the cookie and have the visitor make the choice again when they revisit the cart page. In summary:... they are in cart page, make their selection, cookie is stored... then they visit for example the shop page (or any other page of the website), the cookie gets deleted, and when they revisit the cart page (same session), they have to make again the same selection (thus setting the cookie again).

In order to delete the cookie, I 've inserted temporarily this script in the header of my website (before the closing of the head tag).

```
    // Delete cookie
// store url on load

var currentPage = window.location.href;
var cookiePage = 'http://localhost/my-site/cart/';

// listen for changes
setInterval(function()
{
    console.log(currentPage);
    if (currentPage != cookiePage)
    {

        document.cookie = "option=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        var cookieValue = 0;
    }
}, 500);
```

This script is trying to check the current url and see if it matches the url of the cart page. This check is done every half a second. If the user isn't in the cart page, the script should theoretically delete the cookie...

As you correctly guessed... it doesn't work.... Any help to make it work will be hugely appreciated. The goal is to delete the cookie when the visitor leaves the cart page. Btw, I know there is the solution of onbeforeunload and to call a function to empty the cookie but I don't want this solution. Using onbeforeunload deletes the cookie whenever I click on "update cart" button in the cart page and I don't want this (the cart page gets updated via ajax when I click on "update cart").

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I managed after a million trials and errors. I decided to bind the cookie delete function when clicking on any menu item. It was so simple after all :(.